# How to properly define the [float] data type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point

I defined (through PHPMYADMIN) a field with the `float` data type.
When I try to insert a number as 78.556677099932222377 it will translate it to 79.
How do I make it to save the correct number, at least 7 places after the decimal dot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open phpMyAdmin with structure option and define the float as:

```
FLOAT(23,19)
```

clear in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

How do you define the float in phpMyAdmin

```
FLOAT(23,19)
```

when u declare the field you could use that above.

Better to go with Cygnusx1 and change to decimal

see [MySQL numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

and also [Problems with Float](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)

Answer (score 3):

DECIMAL is what you looking for.

ref:

SQL Decimal is used to specify the values in decimal datatype. The Decimal datatype can be of two types : Decimal (p) refers to floating point and Decimal fixed point (p,s). The DECIMAL data type can store decimal floating-point numbers up to a maximum of 32 significant digits and Decimal fixed point can store upto 16 significant digits.

Comment: You will probably have to set the precision and scale too. Precison for the lenght of the number to the left of the .  and scale for the lenght of your decimal part.

Comment: DECIMAL in MySQL has slightly different parameters (e.g. DECIMAL(p) is a synonym for DECIMAL(p,0))